# Formatting text for WebView Android Studio

Tags: android, html, webview

first time question here.
So, I am uploading text to a WebView, in order to use the `<p align = "justify">`.
However, I am also trying to indent every first line of every chapter using `&nbsp;` for the spaces. But the indents don't always match, some have three spaces, some four, etc... I've tried using `<pre>`, `&#160;` `&xa0;` but to no avail.
My code is as follows:

```
webView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
text ="<font color=\"#2C2C2C\"><html><body><p align=\"justify\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TextTextTextText<br>" +
                "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MoreTextTextText</p></body></html></font>";

text2.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Sorry, truly first time here. There was an "Hello everyone" at the beggining of my question that got cut somehow :P Also, I've tried using <pre> and &#160;...  Thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: Do you need to do it dynamically? Do you generate your html in code?

Comment: I am hardcoding the spaces at the beggining of every new line.

Comment: add a style to your html, that is the right way not &nbsp...

Comment: I've seen CSS at codeacademy, but I am unsure as to how to use it in an android studio project... Could you explain how I should go about it?

Comment: Never mind that... I've found it!! Thank you for pointing me towards the style!!